# How to get highlighted text of UITextView in UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview, uitextview, uimenucontroller

I have a custom cell (subclass of UITableViewCell) with a textView inside of it. It works great! Now, when I tap on a cell and highlight some text, the default UIMenuController appears and I can choose to copy the highlighted text. Also this function works perfectly. Now, I would like to add a custom button to the UIMenuController, which I actually did, but to perform the menu item action I need to know what the selected text is. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain this better, there is no method in `UITextField` that allows us to know what the currently selected text is. But we can leverage the `copy` action on the text field that is associated with the menu controller. The `copy` action copies the text onto the pasteboard which we will need to retrieve. I was able to implement a `Log` function in my custom subclass of `UITextField` like this –

```
- (void)log:(id)sender {
    [self copy:sender];
    NSString *highlightedText = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
    NSLog(@"%@", highlightedText);
}
```

This logs the selected text onto the console. Doesn't do much but gives you the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if it's possible to call the method used by the menu's Copy button? That would be a smoother work around for me…

Comment: It is the same thing I've used - `copy:` as listed [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html).